# Need to find a value that matches two columns of criteria. Possible VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**Update Below -- 6/4**

I have two worksheets in excel. One is a list of donors with their check#/amount/ Donor ID ( "*donations*" worksheet) and the other is a copy of the accounting info with Donor ID/check#/amounts (*quickbooks* worksheet). Quickbooks does not have the DonorID's filled in yet.

The issue I have is that i need match up Donor ID's with their checks. To get this i need to match the `check#` and `amount` in "Quickbooks" to the same in "Donations",  when they match,  it will give me the Donor ID that corresponds with that check.

Here is how it is laid out:

```
Donations Worksheet:
     A                  B           C
 DonationID           Check#     Amount
1   179                106        $200
2   210                106        $500
3   220                106        $600

Quickbooks Worksheet:
      A                B          C
  DonationID         Check#     Amount
1    n/a              106        200
2    N/a              1074       500
3    N/a              300        1000
```

When I ask to find "check# 106 is for $200"  it should tell me that it is from Donor 179.

Some checks don't match and are not from donors. The list has close to 50000 names.

Please ask me any questions so i can clarify this more. I am also somewhat new to all this and apologize if I am not to clear.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Thanks everyone for your help. We are not there yet but you were all steering me in the right direction.

I have added a screen shot of the page for reference because the team was having issues making the given formula's work. I also combined the two sheets onto one page so there is less cross worksheet referencing and will be easier to read.

**Cknum = Check#**

[image: worksheet]

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: vlookup can match on check or amount, but not both, as I suspect you have already discovered.

Comment: @rajah9 - A two-column-lookup is common for [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a)/[MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) pairs and can be either an array formula or a standard formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two column matches typically come in one of two typical configurations; one being an *array* formula and the other being a *standard* formula. Both use variations of an [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a)/[MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) function pair.

[image: Two column Match with INDEX MATCH]

The *standard* formula for Quickbooks!A2 would be,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Donations!A$1:A$999, MIN(INDEX(ROW($1:$999)+((Donations!B$1:B$999<>B2)+(Donations!C$1:C$999<>C2))*1E+99, , ))), "No match")
```

The *array* formula version for Quickbooks!A2 would be,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Donations!A$1:A$999, MATCH(1, (Donations!B$1:B$999=B2)*(Donations!C$1:C$999=C2), 0)), "no match")
```

Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd> rather than simply <kbd>Enter↵</kbd>.

Once one of the formulas has been put in Quickbooks!A2 correctly, fill down as necessary to catch the values from other rows. Note that I have changed the third line of your sample data to demonstrate a second *DonationID* lookup for *Check#* 106.

With ~50K records, there is the distinct possibility that multiple matches could be made on both columns B and C. To capture the subsequent *second, third, etc* matches from the *Donations* worksheet, change the [MIN function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MIN-function-735E28B8-829A-413A-BA38-668FCF0520D7) to a [SMALL function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SMALL-function-4050a82e-659a-4ef6-a970-c963a6f69c29) and use a progressive [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED) to adjust the *k* ordinal.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Donations!A$1:A$50000, SMALL(INDEX(ROW($1:$50000)+((Donations!B$1:B$50000<>B2)+(Donations!C$1:C$50000<>C2))*1E+99, , ), COUNTIFS(B$2:B2, B2, C$2:C2, C2))), "No match")
```

After setting up some intentional duplicates in the *Donations* worksheet like this,

```
DonationID  Check#  Amount
179         106    $200 
210         106    $500 
220         106    $600 
979         106    $200 
910         106    $500 
920         106    $600
```

You should receive results like the following.

[image: Two column Matches with duplicates]

The [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) has been used to catch non-matches and show *no match* rather than the `#N/A` error.

I have modified the values in your single worksheet sample data to show a variety of matches as well as one case where the *chknum* and *amount* were duplicated by two different *donationID* entries.

[image: VLOOKUP multiple criteria with duplicates]

The matching records are color-coded for quick reference. I've made this sample workbook publically available at my Docs.com-Preview site.

[VLOOKUP_w_Multiple_Criteria_and_Duplicates.xlsx](https://dd.docs.com/en-US/d/vlookup-w-multiple-criteria-and-duplicates_Dg2gZJWmZMDQXQAAVFjYicA%7eM6ca7a073-f15a-38a5-79a2-bda619e06ac7)

Comment: what does the 1E+99 correspond with? I can match the rest of the cells but not sure what "1E+99" means.

Comment: It is just a convenient way to describe an impossibly high number; e.g. a *1* followed by *99* zeroes. Anything that is not *both* B2 and C2 has its row number multiplied by 1E+99 to put it out of scope for anything on the worksheet. This method is known as mathematical exclusion. If you remove everything that doesn't fit both conditions, what is left is the answer.

Comment: BTW, you may wish to add a conditional formatting rule based upon the formula `=COUNTIFS(Donations!B$1:B$999, B2, Donations!C$1:C$999, C2)>1`. This could highlight (in red backfill perhaps) any records that produce duplicates on both columns B and C. With ~50K records, this is a possibility. If you have these duplicates, the standard formula could be adjusted to secure the *first, second, third, etc* matches.

Comment: @Elia - See my modification to adjust for duplicate two column matches

Comment: we worked with the formula and could not make it work. I uploaded a image of the worksheet for reference. The results just didn't seem to work out. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: I'm still chewing on the standard version (never seen that form before), but I see no reason the array version does not work.  Hopefully it's clear to OP that `A$999` and `B$999` in the ranges needs to extend all the way through the data?  The multiple check is very slick although I would flag those on the data side since the assumption here is that they should be unique.  (A quick `remove duplicates` would tell you if there were any).

Comment: @Elia  -See my modification above and the link to the sample workbook.

Comment: @Byron - I was thinking that this was some sort of general ledger for a charity receiving donations. From that point of view, several cheques from several people could potentially have the same cheque number and amount.

Comment: @Jeeped, I get the same sense on scope and agree the clashes could be possible and an issue.  My assumption though is that this match is being done to reconcile two systems which might have more data fields not shown.  In that sense (if this was my task) I would prefer to flag the clash rather than assign donation IDs arbitrarily.  You could imagine the next branch of this problem is finding which clashed entries are closest based on date.

Comment: @Jeeped, smart answer, with your permission I will use your sample data to show another possibility. Cheers..

Comment: @EEM - No worries. It makes no sense for everyone to have to retype all of those values and using the same data makes different solutions directly comparable. Nice *'helper column'* answer! Given the image of the data that hte OP supplied I strongly suspect that they were referencing the wrong columns when attempting to use my solution for their own purposes; e.g. column V's *cknum* values were formatted as currency.

Answer (score 1):

There is an existing command, DGET, that can be used for multiple criteria.

In your QB worksheet, I added another few rows, starting at A7.

```
ID      CheckNo  Amount
        106      200

    The ID is   179
```

Note that I changed Check# to CheckNo. I also added a definition of `donationDB`, from A1 to D4.

The DGet statement is where the 179 is. I used `=DGET(donationDB,Donations!B1,Quickbooks!A7:C8)`

What the DGET does is to look up the database, tell it you're looking for the Donor ID in B1, using the criteria in the fields A7 to C8.

Comment: It's like a formula version of the `Advanced Filter`.  Never knew about that one.  Note it will return `#NUM!` if there are multiple matches.  This might also be difficult to copy down a page.  Could build a massive `Data Table` to handle that.

Answer (score 1):

One quick way out of this problem is to create a Pivot Table on the `Donations` data and then use `GETPIVOTDATA` to pull values out of it to get the donation id on the `Quickbooks` table.

This is easily done if the donation ID is always numeric.  You set up a Pivot Table with row fields including check number and amount.  You then set the values to be equal to `MIN` or `MAX` of the donation ID.  If there is only one result you will get it immediately.  If there is a clash, you can determine this by switching over to `COUNT` and flag any of those `>1`.

Once you have the table set up with `MAX` you can then quickly use `GETPIVOTDATA` to pull in the matching value.

This assumes that your `amount` values are close enough (in the floating point decimal sense) to match.  Nearly all will be.  Some may not.  If you can get 50k records down to 100 though to double check, then life is good.

**Picture of sample data and Pivot set up**, shows the Pivot Table built on the left data (with the donation ID).  The lookup data is on the right.

[image: data and pivot]

**Formula** for the lookup is a simple `GETPIVOTDATA`, this is in cell `F3` and copied down.

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("Donation",$B$10,"Check",G3,"Amount",H3)
```

You will get the `#REF!` error if a match is not made.  See the last row for an example.

Answer (score 1):

To compare two sets of data by matching several fields and obtain another field as a result of the match, I suggest to add a new field to each database to create a concatenated value of the Fields to match, then use a `VLOOKUP` and `COUNTIF` formulas combined.

Let’s use the sample data provided by Jeeped, in which we have:
Data A: Quickbooks - range `D1:M24` and Data B: Donations – range `R1:W23`, to be extended to `C1:M24` and `Q1:W23` respectively

1. Add Field “Key” to concatenate the Fields to match *(2 fields in this case, but also works for more)*, use `|` as separator.

Data A: Add Field “Key” in Column `C` and enter this formula

```
=CONCATENATE($E2,"|",$M2)
```

Data B: Add Field “Key” in Column `Q` and enter this formula

```
=CONCATENATE($V2,"|",$W2)
```

2. Enter formulas to match concatenated fields and retrieve required information *(also indicates items duplicated)*

Data A: Add this formula in column `N`

```
=IF(COUNTIF($Q$1:$Q$23,$C2)>1,
"Duplicated: "&COUNTIF($Q$1:$Q$23,$C2),
IFERROR(VLOOKUP($C2,$Q$1:$W$23,2,0),""))
```

[image]

Data B: Add this formula in column `X`

```
=IF(COUNTIF($C$1:$M$24,$Q5)>1,
"Duplicated: "&COUNTIF($C$1:$M$24,$Q5),
IFERROR(VLOOKUP($Q5,$C$1:$M$24,2,0),""))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I use the `AVERAGEIFS` function for getting a numeric value based on multiple criteria.  If you are not confident that the criteria would only return one value, then you can wrap in a `COUNTIFS` statement.

`=IF(COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$10, crit1, $B$1:$B$10, crit2) = 1, AVERAGEIFS($C$1:C$10, $A$1:$A$10, crit1, $B$1:$B$10, crit2), #N/A)`

This only works for numeric values though.