# Get value from range if cells match in Excel

Tags: excel

Excuse me for the messy title, hope I would explain the problem below clearer.

This is an example what table I do have: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9JSj.png

This is formula I use: `=INDEX($G:$G, MATCH(B$1,$F:$F,0))`

The task is: if types *id* and *idnum* match, and column name (A, B and C) matches value in *type* -> put value of the cell from *value* to the A, B or C column. I tried to search how to do this as well as trying out to do this with =IF and Index, Match, Match, but nothing worked out.

Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: So all you are looking for is a [two column match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33010190/two-column-lookup-in-table-array-using-index-and-match/33011266#33011266) or a [two column match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37157967/two-column-lookup-with-a-cell-value-falling-in-with-a-prerequisite-range/37158518#37158518) or a [two column match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30628109/need-to-find-a-value-that-matches-two-columns-of-criteria-possible-vlookup/30629134#30629134)...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Formula in `B2` cell

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($G$2:$G$15,MATCH(1,($E$2:$E$15=$A2)*($F$2:$F$15=B$1),0)),"")
```

After click `F2` and `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter`

[image]

Comment: Thanks you, exactly what I needed!